# How to get CSV file data from an S3 bucket into an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a pretty broad topic question that I'm hoping my  AWS/web developer friends can help me out with. I have an S3 bucket containing a CSV file of data. My goal is to display the data through the form of an HTML table on my website.

The CSV file consists of lists with several values each, which is how I am going to format it. I need to read the CSV file, separate the list by the first element value (a string), and then display data on separate pages associative to the first index element. I have used the boto3 library with Python for extracting the data and then formatting it myself, but I have no experience integrating Python functions with web pages so I am at a loss. Would a Lambda function be the best way to do this? Should I turn the data into a JSON array?

The CSV format is something like this (obviously not the actual data)

```
'''
['Apple', red, large, sweet],
['Apple', green, small, sour],
['Apple', red, small, sour],
['Orange', orange, medium, sweet] and so on...
'''
```

I intend to separate the data according to the value in the first index of the list. For my website, different pages will contain a table of the data correlative to the index. So, clicking on the 'Apple' page would display all the instances in the csv file with 'Apple' as the first index and the subsequent data, and so on for Orange. That would look something like

```
                        red       large       sweet
                        green     small       sour
                        red       small       sour
```

I know this is a very large question. I'm new to both AWS Lambda and to JavaScript and seeking some direction more than anything else. Thank you!

Comment: A webpage, via JavaScript, could read the CSV file and present it.  A Lambda could read the CSV and output a JSON object for JavaScript to use, or HTML directly.  The component uploading the CSV file could also upload a HTML page.  There are many options, the best option depends on many external factors.

Comment: Are you wanting the HTML page to retrieve the data directly from S3, or will the backend be accessing S3 and sending the resulting HTML to the browser? (I notice you added a `boto3` tag, which is the AWS SDK for Python.)

Comment: I'm hoping the HTML Page will retrieve data directly from S3. I initially was using the boto3 library, but if I can do it through JavaScript that is definitely preferred